# how to set boolean value to a variable inside an array and check for that value using node js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, for-loop

I want to set a boolean value "true" to a variable inside the flags[ ]. Then when all the variables inside the flags[ ] are true, I need to do an operation.

Please find my code below.

```
var flags = [terminationFlag,transferFlag,jrCancelledFlag,jrFilledFlag,jrOpenFlag,miegFlags,headcountFlag,replacementReqFlag,costcentreFlag,gradeMapFlag]

var arguments = ["terminationReport - 2019-1", "transferReport - 2019-1", "jrCancelledReport - 2019-1", "jrFilledReport - 2019-1", "jrOpenReport - 2019-1","MIEGReport - 2019-1", "HeadCountReport - 2019-1","ReplacementReport - 2019-1","CostcentreReport - 2019-1","GradeMapReport - 2019-1"]

for (i=0; i < arguments.length ;i++){
    console.log("arguments : "+ arguments[i]);
    request('http://localhost:3000/query/CheckKey/'+arguments[i], function (error, response, body) {
        var result = JSON.stringify(response.body).replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
        if (result == "yes"){
            console.log("record found ****************");
            flags[i]=true;
            console.log("flags : "+ flags);
        }
       if flags = true {
           //do operation
        }
    });

}
```

But it is not working. Please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: Is the flags part the only part that is not working in your code?

Comment: yes @holydragon. i need to set the value to the varaibles inside the flags [ ]. so that i can check the values inside the flags [ ] == true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you're running an asynchronous operation inside `for` loop. Since you haven't declared `i`, it's created as a global variable. The `for` loop just fires the requests and won't wait for the callbacks to run. By the time `request` is done, the value of `i` is changed to something else and you end up assigning `true` to wrong `flag` items. So, change it to:

```
arguments.forEach((arg, i) => {
  console.log("arguments : " + arg);
  request('http://localhost:3000/query/CheckKey/' + arg, function(error, response, body) {
    var result = JSON.stringify(response.body).replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
    if (result == "yes") {
      console.log("record found ****************");
      flags[i] = true;
      console.log("flags : " + flags);
    }
    if flags = true {
      //do operation
    }
  });
})
```

Or use `let`:

```
for (let i=0; i < arguments.length ;i++){

}
```

Comment: thank you for the response.it works. is there any possibility that i can set the values like terminationFlag = true, transferFlag = true, jrCancelledFlag = true, jrFilledFlag = true. so that i can check like                                                          
         if (terminationFlag = true && transferFlag = true && jrCancelledFlag  = true && jrFilledFlag = true) { //do some operation }

Comment: @Priyanka You can's keep reference to boolean values. You'd have to create an object with all those properties as key values. Or you'd have to use a[`Boolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) object

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether every element in `flags` is true, use [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
if (flags.every(flag => flag)) {...}
```

Or if your browser doesn't support ES6:

```
if (flags.every(function(flag) {
    return flag;
})) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here.

First, this for-loop should use **let** to iterate especially when you use asynchronous function(s) inside the loop because each iteration will hold the i value for each loop.

```
for (let i=0; i < arguments.length ;i++){
```

Second,

```
if flags = true {
    //do operation
}
```

You have to use any form of loop to check if all of the flags in the flags array are true. You could use [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) like in Jack Bashford's answer.

I recommend an ordinary for-loop since it is better performance-wise.

```
let allFlagsTrue = true
for (let j = 0; j < flags.length; j++){
    if (flags[i] === false){
        allFlagsTrue = false
    }
}
if (allFlagsTrue){
    // Do your operations
}
```